# Word opposite to "warm-up" in sports?

Tags: word-request

Which word is opposite to "warm-up" in sports? I mean slow running, gentle exercise after hard work to accelerate recovery processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cooling down.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooling_down) A cool down is an easy exercise that will allow the body to gradually transition to a resting or near-resting state.

Example:

> When you workout you should always incorporate a warm up before and a
>   cool down afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

[Warm-down](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/warm-down) is broadly used especially in running or racing as indicated in the below definition:

> a tapering off or recovery from strenuous physical exercise,
>   especially running or racing, by slowing down or doing light
>   stretches.

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Number of results returned by Google 
warm-down - 13 mn.
cool-down - 60 mn.
So I think cool-down is more common

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko Yes, I suggested another term. Cool-down is the most popular term.